# My contents in bootsrapt tab not showed althought the script is similiar

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am first in bootsrapt, i want show 3 tabs which have content, my first tab is working but my second tab and third tab is nor working although the id of tabel is different. my tabs id also have different name. This my Code, my question is what my problem in this code, i want show 3 tabs.

```
          <div class="panel panel-default tabs">  
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                     <li class="active"><a href="#tab-first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Universitas</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#tab-second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fakultas</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#tab-third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Prodi</a></li>
                                    </ul>                   
                    <div class="panel-body tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-first">
                     <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                     <table id="universitas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                      <thead>
                                       <tr>
                                       <th>No</th>
                                       <th>Tahun Akademik</th>
                                       <th>Pro Kehadiran Mahasiswa</th>
                                       <th>Pro Kehadiran Dosen</th>
                                       <th>Rata - Rata IPK</th>
                                       <th>Nilai A</th>
                                       <th>Nilai B</th>
                                       <th>Nilai C</th>
                                       <th>Nilai D</th>
                                       <th>Nilai E</th>
                                       </tr>
                                 </thead>
                 <?php
                         $no = 1;
                         $sql_ipk   = mysql_query("SELECT proMhs, proDsn, avgIpk, Nilai_A, Nilai_B, Nilai_C, Nilai_D, Nilai_E FROM v_akademik WHERE TAHUN>='$tahun_awal' and TAHUN <= '$tahun_akhir' group by TAHUN");
                           $tahun_end = $tahun_awal+1; 
                         while( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $sql_ipk) ){

                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$no</td>
                                <td>$tahun_awal - $tahun_end</td>
                                <td>$data[proMhs] %</td>
                                <td>$data[proDsn] %</td>
                                <td>$data[avgIpk]</td>
                                <td>$data[Nilai_A] %</td>
                                <td>$data[Nilai_B] %</td>
                                <td>$data[Nilai_C] %</td>
                                <td>$data[Nilai_D] %</td>
                                <td>$data[Nilai_E] %</td>


                            </tr>";
                             $no++;
                            $tahun_awal++;
                            $tahun_end++;



                        }

                            ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </div>



                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-second">
                            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                <table id="universitas2" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
                                    <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                            <th>No</th>
                                            <th>Tahun Akademik</th>
                                            <th>Pro Kehadiran Mahasiswa</th>
                                            <th>Pro Kehadiran Dosen</th>
                                             <th>Rata - Rata IPK</th>
                                             <th>Nilai A</th>
                                             <th>Nilai B</th>
                                             <th>Nilai C</th>
                                             <th>Nilai D</th>
                                             <th>Nilai E</th>
                                        </tr>

                                   </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                             $no = 1;
                                             $sql_ipk   = mysql_query("SELECT proMhs, proDsn, avgIpk, Nilai_A, Nilai_B, Nilai_C, Nilai_D, Nilai_E FROM v_akademik WHERE TAHUN>='$tahun_awal' and TAHUN <= '$tahun_akhir' group by TAHUN, NM_FAKULTAS");
                                               $tahun_end = $tahun_awal+1; 
                                             while( $data2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sql_ipk) ){

                                            echo "
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>$no</td>
                                                    <td>$tahun_awal - $tahun_end</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[proMhs] %</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[proDsn] %</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[avgIpk]</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[Nilai_A] %</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[Nilai_B] %</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[Nilai_C] %</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[Nilai_D] %</td>
                                                    <td>$data2[Nilai_E] %</td>


                                                </tr>";
                                                 $no++;
                                                $tahun_awal++;
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-third">
                            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                <table id="universitas" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No</th>
                                            <th>Tahun Akademik</th>
                                            <th>Pro Kehadiran Mahasiswa</th>
                                            <th>Pro Kehadiran Dosen</th>
                                             <th>Rata - Rata IPK</th>
                                             <th>Nilai A</th>
                                             <th>Nilai B</th>
                                             <th>Nilai C</th>
                                             <th>Nilai D</th>
                                             <th>Nilai E</th>
                                        </tr>


                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                         <?php
                                                 $no = 1;
                                                 $sql_ipk   = mysql_query("SELECT proMhs, proDsn, avgIpk, Nilai_A, Nilai_B, Nilai_C, Nilai_D, Nilai_E FROM v_akademik WHERE TAHUN>='$tahun_awal' and TAHUN <= '$tahun_akhir' group by TAHUN, NM_FAKULTAS, NM_PRODI");
                                                   $tahun_end = $tahun_awal+1; 
                                                 while( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $sql_ipk) ){

                                                echo "
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>$no</td>
                                                        <td>$tahun_awal - $tahun_end</td>
                                                        <td>$data[proMhs] %</td>
                                                        <td>$data[proDsn] %</td>
                                                        <td>$data[avgIpk]</td>
                                                        <td>$data[Nilai_A] %</td>
                                                        <td>$data[Nilai_B] %</td>
                                                        <td>$data[Nilai_C] %</td>
                                                        <td>$data[Nilai_D] %</td>
                                                        <td>$data[Nilai_E] %</td>
                                                    </tr>";
                                                     $no++;
                                                    $tahun_awal++;
                                                    $tahun_end++;

                                                }
                                                ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div> 
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: your second tab-pane is duplicated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?? i think the way you are accessing, `data[]` is wrong.

Comment: my data in tabledata is no available. so what can i do to accesing data?

Comment: **[Working fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/89t9kjL5/)**. Can you explain **not working**?